# Can I skip the launcher when launching Baldur's Gate 3 from Steam?

Tags: steam, baldurs-gate-3

I don't want to have to go through the "Larian Launcher" when I want to play Baldur's Gate 3 in Steam. How can I skip it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To skip the launcher in Baldur's Gate 3:

1. Right-click the game in the Steam game list and choose "Properties..."
2. Add the following in the "Launch Options" option in the "General" tab that opens:

   `--skip-launcher`

Now hitting "play" in Steam will directly open the game, skipping the launcher.

Comment: Oh my, this is going to save me so. Much. Time. Thanks!

Comment: Great! And is there a way to automatically have it click "continue" also? Because 99% of the time, that's what I want, and the 1% where I really want the main menu, I'll just change the option (or load and switch back).

Comment: First, just make sure that the most suitable gfx engine for your rig is picked: Direct X 11 or Vulkan. This is done from the launcher. Which one that runs fastest/prettiest is apparently a bit subjective. You might want to toy around with graphic tweaks and try both engines before anything else. The game tends to chew a lot of GPU.